# unable to print UTF8 document using Java Print Service API on windows

Tags: java

I have been trying to print a text document containing Russian letters using the Java Print Service API on windows OS, but no luck so far. The printer prints the file, but the unicode characters get garbled.

While running the program, the VM argument **-Dfile.encoding=utf8** was specified

### Following is the code

```
    import java.io.DataInputStream;  
    import java.io.FileInputStream;  
    import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;  
    import javax.print.Doc;  
    import javax.print.DocFlavor;  
    import javax.print.DocPrintJob;  
    import javax.print.PrintException;  
    import javax.print.PrintService;  
    import javax.print.PrintServiceLookup;  
    import javax.print.SimpleDoc;  
    import javax.print.attribute.HashPrintRequestAttributeSet;  
    import javax.print.attribute.PrintRequestAttributeSet;  
    import javax.print.attribute.standard.Sides;  


    public class PrintUtf8Doc {


        public static void main(String[] args) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {  
            FileInputStream textstream=null;   
            DataInputStream da=null;  
            byte buff[]=new byte[1024*20];  

            try {  
                textstream = new FileInputStream("D:\\test\\russian.txt");   
                da=new DataInputStream(textstream);  
                da.read(buff);  

            } catch (Exception e) {   
                e.printStackTrace();  
            }   
            if (textstream == null) {   
                return; 
            } 
    //       Set the document type

            DocFlavor myFormat = DocFlavor.BYTE_ARRAY.AUTOSENSE;


    //       Create a Doc
            Doc myDoc = new SimpleDoc(buff, myFormat, null);   
    //       Build a set of attributes  
            PrintRequestAttributeSet aset = new HashPrintRequestAttributeSet();   
            aset.add(Sides.DUPLEX);   

            System.out.println("Host Encoding: "+myFormat.hostEncoding);  


            PrintService service = PrintServiceLookup.lookupDefaultPrintService();  
            DocFlavor flavs[]=service.getSupportedDocFlavors();
            for(DocFlavor flavor: flavs){
              System.out.println(flavor.toString());                
            }

            // Create a print job from one of the print services  
            if (service!=null) {   

                DocPrintJob printJob=service.createPrintJob();  
                try {  
                    printJob.print(myDoc, aset);  
                } catch (PrintException e) {  
                    e.printStackTrace();  
                }               

            }

        }
    }

-------------------------------------------------------------------
The supported flavors are printed in the console

Host Encoding: UTF8  
image/gif; class="[B"  
image/gif; class="java.io.InputStream"  
image/gif; class="java.net.URL"  
image/jpeg; class="[B"  
image/jpeg; class="java.io.InputStream"  
image/jpeg; class="java.net.URL"  
image/png; class="[B"  
image/png; class="java.io.InputStream"  
image/png; class="java.net.URL"  
application/x-java-jvm-local-objectref; class="java.awt.print.Pageable"  
application/x-java-jvm-local-objectref; class="java.awt.print.Printable"  
application/octet-stream; class="[B"  
application/octet-stream; class="java.net.URL"  
application/octet-stream; class="java.io.InputStream"
```

---

I tried even changing the docFlavor to 
"application/octet-stream; class="java.io.InputStream"
and passed the inputStream to the SimpleDoc() constructor, but still it was the same issue

Looks like even if the platform encoding was set to UTF8, the Java Print Service on windows is not able to ode the bytes correctly.

Is there any setting that needs to be done or corrected?
Any suggestions would be of great help

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to read russian.txt in `UTF-8`, I think since the file contains `UTF-8` character but being read in `windows-1252` (default encoding if not specified in Java)  this conversion might resulting into garbled characters.

You can use `InputStreamReader` which takes charset as read (see last parameter below):

```
BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(f), "UTF-8"));
```

If it is required to have byte[] then you need to deduce way to convert it from above reader as these exposes `char` based read APIs (and readLine as well in case of buffered reader)

Comment: Thanks for you response Harsh   I had tried out that earlier. However if you see the supported flavors for the printer on window, it takes in either a byte array or an input stream. I tried reading the bytes with an input stream with UTF-8 encoding.   Actually this is not required,since the JVM property -Dfile.encoding has been set to UTF-8

Comment: Ok so is converting from readers to byte[] is your problem? can you post a sample line of text having Russian letters..

Comment: Harsh its something like the byte[] array read from the file is in UTF8 format. This can be confirmed by writing the same byte[] array to temp file. You open the temp file and you can see that the file would contain russian characters. Just forget the file. Say you create a simple String with russian characters String str=new String("Это пример") and then get the bytes out of it byte buff[]=str.getBytes("UTF-8") and send byte[] to the print service, it prints the garbled characters

Comment: Also i tried to write a BOM character '\ufeff' before the byte array to signal to the print service that the incoming byte[] is in UTF-8 format. This too didnt work.